# convex hull and surface area

Tags: geometry, area

Is it true that the surface area of a convex hull of a non-convex polyhedron is not greater than the surface area of the non-convex polygon?

I believe this to be false.  I believe that they can have equal surface areas.  I picture a box with the corner pushed in.  If we push the corner back out to form the box correctly, they would have the same surface area.  I don't know how to explain this mathematically.

Comment: But cvxhull(box with pushed corner)$\ne$cvxhull(box).

Comment: any ideas on how to pursue this problem?

Comment: I suppose that will be nontrivial and related with the isoperimetric inequality.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true that the surface area of a convex hull of a non-convex polyhedron is not greater than the surface area of the non-convex [polyhedron]?

No. The surface area of convex hull can be much larger. Think of a dumbbell: namely, take two balls of radius $1$ with centers at $(\pm n,0)$ and connect them by an extremely thin cylinder. The resulting shape has surface area just a little over $2\cdot 4\pi = 8\pi$. But the boundary of its convex hull contains a cylinder of radius $1$ and height $2n$. So, its area is at least $4\pi n$. And $n$ could be arbitrarily large.

The above are not polyhedra, but you can just as well replace balls with cubes and connect them by a very thin squarish cylinder. The convex hull is a long rectangular box whose surface area is much larger than the surface area of the original polyhedron.

---

**In the plane**, taking convex hull does not increase the perimeter. But this does not generalize to higher dimensions.